# Convert oracle sql timestamp to char coldfusion

Tags: sql, oracle, coldfusion, timestamp, to-char

What I am trying to do is converting the oracle timestamp to_char so it is readable by the human eye.

The following is my SQL code:

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="hdlbillDetails">
    SELECT BILLID, FIRSTNAME, 
           LASTNAME, RESIDENCE, 
           STREET, TOWN, 
           COUNTRY, AMMOUNTDUE, 
           to_char(DATEDUE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'), 
           to_char(DATEISSUES,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')
    FROM Details
    WHERE BillID = #billId#
</cfquery>
```

The Error shown is the following:

```
Caused by: coldfusion.runtime.UndefinedElementException: 
Element DATEDUE is undefined in HDLBILLDETAIL
```

Comment: Do you have DATEDUE in your table ? check spell or existance

Comment: Yes if I remove the to_char part and write only DATEDUE the data is retrieved as oracle.sql.TIMESTAMP@26d780b6

Comment: Please use `<cfqueryparam>` in your query where you're using `#billID#`, otherwise you leave yourself open to all sorts of problems

Comment: billID is being retrieved from the database from another function so I don't have any problem there.

Comment: Even if billID is coming from another database, there are still advantages to using query params.  Increased performance and escaping special characters are two of them.

Comment: Ok thanks. I'll keep it in mind in the future.

Comment: Just to confirm what Dunc and Dan have said: parameterising your data values is not just about SQL injection, it's *mostly* about keeping your data separate from your SQL statements. If you do, then your DB will have more luck maintaining it's execution plan. If you hardcode values into your SQL, then the DB needs to compile every single time you make the query, as opposed to ONCE if you use parameters.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Untested, but try this.  It might be just a need for aliases on the calculations:

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="hdlbillDetails">
    SELECT BILLID, FIRSTNAME, 
           LASTNAME, RESIDENCE, 
           STREET, TOWN, 
           COUNTRY, AMMOUNTDUE, 
           to_char(DATEDUE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DATEDUE, 
           to_char(DATEISSUES,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DATEISSUES
    FROM Details
    WHERE BillID = #billId#
</cfquery>
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Never thought it was due to not having aliases.

Answer (score 2):

try using alias e.g

```
<cfquery datasource="#application.dsn#" name="hdlbillDetails">
    SELECT d.BILLID, d.FIRSTNAME, 
           d.LASTNAME, d.RESIDENCE, 
           d.STREET, d.TOWN, 
           d.COUNTRY, d.AMMOUNTDUE, 
           to_char(d.DATEDUE,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DATEDUE, 
           to_char(d.DATEISSUES,'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') as DATEISSUES
    FROM Details d
    WHERE d.BillID = #billId#
</cfquery>
```